# need to run specific functionality at specific interval in java

Tags: java

I have a specific requirement.

I have a notification functionality which sends the email to all the systems clients.
The code is written in java.

What i want to do is, i want to execute that specific job which sends the email at specific intervals like once in a 2 days or once in a week or a month.

As of now i don't have a clue about how to do this. We are using Quartz but I think that wont fit into my requirement as of now.

Please let me know if anyone has any idea.

Answer (score 1):

use scheduling and take a look [here](http://quartz-scheduler.org/)

Answer (score 1):

Why not use a [`ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor`](http://tutorials.jenkov.com/java-util-concurrent/scheduledexecutorservice.html) which allows you to schedule tasks to execute in future.

```
ScheduledExecutorService scheduledExecutorService =
        Executors.newScheduledThreadPool(5);

ScheduledFuture scheduledFuture =
    scheduledExecutorService.schedule(new Callable() {
        public Object call() throws Exception {
            System.out.println("Executed!");
            return "Called!";
        }
    },
    5,
    TimeUnit.SECONDS);
```